# repeat button wpf not firing off click event

Tags: wpf, xaml, repeatbutton

Hello community I have the following xaml.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.SampleController"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="410" d:DesignWidth="324">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="buttonON" TargetType="RepeatButton">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                        <Grid Width="80"
                              Height="80">
                            <Image Source="/Sample;component/icons/altitude_up_yellow.png"  
                                   Stretch="Fill" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Name="DriveGrid" Background="#C9000000" Width="324" Height="410">

        <RepeatButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  IsEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource buttonON}"  Margin="232,297,0,0" Delay="100" Interval="200" Width="80" Height="80"/>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the following Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;



namespace Sample {

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SampleController : UserControl {

        public SampleController() {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(UpBtn_Click);

        }

         void UpBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Click");
        }


    }
}
```

My question, why doesn't the repeat button fire off continously when I press and hold?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried setting `Background="Transparent"` on root grid in the template of the button?

Comment: @DoubleDunk, Does it fire only once or never? Don't know if this is  copy/paste error or you mixed controls but your class name is `SampleController` but it has constructor for `CmdController`.

Comment: I am sorry for the copy/paste error, you are absolutely right. To answer your questions, when I press and hold it only fires off the click event once.

Comment: @Stewbob Actually in my case it only fires off once when I click and hold, I do not have to release it button.

Comment: @DoubleDunk, I cannot reproduce it here as it keeps triggering `Click` event. I only found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/5d9dc124-b9d3-48e8-a6f9-c1f9d9a49c20/repeatbutton-fires-event-only-once). Maybe it will give you an idea for a workaround

Comment: Thank you for your comments community, as dkozl suggested it does work when I take it out of my project and make it a standalone wpf application. I have to inspect this further, but for the time being I used a timer/preview_onclick combination to mimic the effect. I would gladly post some source code if anyone is interested. @dkozl If you would post your comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @DoubleDunk, I've posted my comment as an answer. Post your workaround as another answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up comments. Even though I am not able to reproduce the problem stated in the question, as the code above works fine for me, I have found very similar issue in [RepeatButton fires event only once!](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/5d9dc124-b9d3-48e8-a6f9-c1f9d9a49c20/repeatbutton-fires-event-only-once) article. There is no definite answer what's causing the issue but it may give some clues to what to try